# Referencing a time-style definition does not work

Tags: bash, variable

For a given file one may issue the bash command:

```bsh
ls -la --full-time --time-style long-iso --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" file
```

This works of course.

I have a larger script in which I would like to define the time-style and to reference it multiple times:

```bsh
TMP_TIME_STYLE="--full-time --time-style long-iso --time-style=+""%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"""
```

Executing the command

```bsh
ls -la ${TMP_TIME_STYLE} file
```

results in the error message:

```
ls: accessing '%Y-%m-%d' is not possible: no such file or directory.
```

It seems that not all the options in `${TMP_TIME_STYLE}` are passed to `ls`.

I already tried to put additional `""` just in front of `%Y-%m-%d` and immediately behind `%H:%M:%S`, however the same error message.

How to safely pass the contents of `${TMP_TIME_STYLE}` to `ls`?

Comment: You can use an array for the options, as indicated in the duplicate. But for your use-case I'd go with an `alias`. e.g. `alias lst='ls -la --full-time --time-style long-iso --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'`. Then `lst file`.

Comment: note that you don't even have quotes in the value of `TMP_TIME_STYLE`: in `TMP_TIME_STYLE="... --time-style=+""%Y-%m-...`, the second and third quotes just close and reopen the quoted string, the result would be the same with `TMP_TIME_STYLE="...--time-style=+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. Regardless, the quotes wouldn't help, this is what everyone tries and what is explained in the linked question. You could do `TIME_STYLE="--time-style=+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` and `ls -l ... "$TIME_STYLE"` though, but you can't have the string split on one space but not another.

Comment: @pLumo, though they mentioned a script, so in Bash they'd have to explicitly enable them too (`shopt -s expand_aliases`). A function might be better here though.

Comment: I was not aware that aliases won't get expanded in scripts by default ... Good to know :-)